# How to add constraints to a linear set of equations

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, python

I am trying to implement a method from this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8353392). The image (link) below shows the problem.

[image: Minimization problem]

As they describe it, the matrix `D` is a coefficient matrix, `x` is the vecotr of unknown variables, and `d` is a vector of values, mostly 0's but also a few values between 0-1.

Then below they have the constraints, `Ax ≤ c` .

They state that "The term `Ax ≤ c` represents the constraints (as function of the estimated coefficients) for all the pixels in all the images in the set. Each pixel must fulfill two constraints."

In the paper they go on to show that the matrix `A` should contain the minimum and maximum pixel values for each image (rather than including an equation for each image pixel), with one equation for each (so 1 EQ for the max. pixel value of image 1, and 1 EQ for the min. pixel value of image 1, and so on for all `n` images).

Given that they say that the constraints are a function of the estimated coefficients, I don't think I can just add a set of equations into the system of equations represented by `D` can I? How would one best go about implementing the constraints?

I am trying to perform this in Python, so if anyone also has some pointers on which function might be best suited for this problem I would appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @YouKnowMe: I noticed in many question that you include the links as pictures. Please don't do this anymore. New users should learn to fully type out their questions using MathJax (cf. José Carlos Santos' comment).

Comment: @Ernie060 Okay. Can I write LaTeX for old posts so that they can be searched?

Comment: @YouKnowMeThat's not bad, I think. Personally, I avoid to immediately edit the math formulas in posts of new users. Sometimes I tell them in a comment that they should use MathJax (like José's comment above). That way, new users can learn the "etiquette" of the site. If one always edits "ugly math formulas", some users (not all of them...) don't do any effort. Hope this advice is useful.